# Why does the value of count in the data file not increment?

Tags: java, file-handling

Despite writing the integer into the data file, the total bytes available in the file remain 0.

```
public class Q 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("count.dat"));
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("count.dat"));
        if (input.available()==0) 
        {
            output.writeInt(1);
        }
        else
        {
            int count = input.readInt() + 1;
            System.out.println(count);
            output.writeInt(count);
        }
        output.close();
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are accessing the file? Maybe show you're file structure to see if you are calling count.dat correctly

Comment: Yeah, I can access it. The code writes the integer '1' on the file but it does not increment it. Instead, it just rewrites '1' again and again.

Comment: Why are you using `input.available() == 0` ? The `else` statement will never be executed in your example.

Comment: The file is empty when you create it, and you are always creating it, so your incrementing code is never executed. Your claim that the file remains empty is false. The size after running this code is 4 bytes.

Comment: You should be using a single `RandomAccessFile`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem here is that when you create the FileOutputStream, the older data is deleted. As to keep that data, we can choose between two options:

1. The best way to do it is by creating a [RandomAccessFile](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/java_io_randomaccessfile.htm), which behaves like a large array of bytes. It has a great feature supporting both reading and writing. Before analyzing the code, to which I added a few comments, let's see it first.

   ```
   public static void main() throws IOException{

       File file = new File ("count.dat");
       RandomAccessFile RAF = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw"); // rw stands for read and write

       if (RAF.length() == 0){ //Checks if file is empty

           RAF.writeInt(1);
           System.out.println("File was empty!");

       }else{

           int count = RAF.readInt() + 1;
           RAF.seek(0); //file pointer at position 0
           System.out.println(count);
           RAF.writeInt(count);

       }

       RAF.close();

   }
   ```

   Firstly, I declare the RandomAccessFile. There are two parameters, one being the file and the other one the string mode, here's a [list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html): "rw" (read and write), "r", "rws" and "rwd". The first condition checks if the file's length is 0, which means it is empty. In case it is true, we write an int. On the other hand, if it is false, we set the read the integer stored in the file and add one. Then, as the pointer (in terms of position) has moved, we set it back to position 0 (`RAF.seek(0);`). Last but not least, we write the new value, and we close the file.

   A RandomAccessFile is a nice way to combine both reading and writing without deleting the previous content, which in case you wanted to, you would be able.
2. Another way to do it would be to read first and then open the stream.

   ```
   File file = new File ("count.dat");
   DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
   int count = input.readInt();
   ```

   Then, inside the else change the count declaration for `count++;`

Special thanks to [user207421](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/user207421) for warning me about the mistakes on the older version of this post.

Comment: `DataOutputStream` does not delete the old data. `new FileOutputStream(...)` does that. `FileOutputStream` does not inherit from `FileReader`, which does not have an `append` parameter. Appending to the file would not accomplish rewriting the integer value. Closing and immediately reopening the input stream is futile.

Comment: First error remains. There is no such thing as 'conditional `append()`' in `DataOutputStream`, and appending to the file continues not to be a solution, or to have anything to do with the solution whatsoever.. There is nothing 'less efficient' about (2), especially guven that the code in (1) doesn't compile.

Comment: It's not much good thanking me when most of the problems I mentioned remain. It isn't necessary to open the file for output  *at all* to merely *read* the original value, let alone to open it in append mode, and the proof is that you don't do any writing while it is in that mode. For the third time, append mode forms no part of the solution to this problem. It is baffling why you think otherwise. And you still haven't explained why you think opening the file three times is more efficient than two. It isn't.

Comment: All done, now it is fine.